# Retrieving file name and size from OneDrive Content Uri's

Tags: android, uri, onedrive

```
if (fileUri.getScheme().equals(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT)) 
{
            Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(
                    fileUri, 
                    new String[] { android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME }, 
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null);         
            cursor.moveToFirst();   
            fileName = cursor.getString(0);
            cursor.close();
}
```

I am using this block of code to retrieve the name and size of Content Uri's and so far it worked great for all cloud storage applications that provides Content Uri's (OneDrive, Dropbox, Google Drive, Box).

Problem started after OneDrive latest update (Version 2.7.0) that added the option to open files with the storage access framework. When you select a file on Nexus devices via Intent Chooser ("Open From"), OneDrive application appears twice (see sattached screenshot):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/klu11xc8mqi1acu/Screenshot_2014-09-28-11-49-34.png?dl=0

Selecting any file from the "upper" OneDrive will return a Content Uri for which
the file size is always 0 and file name is always the URI itself.
However, selecting any file from the "lower" OneDrive will return a File Uri (cached) for which
the file size and name are the right ones.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For SAF providers you should read item name from DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME (android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY is not SAF concept). 

How are you checking file size? What API are using?

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help. Both  DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME  and android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY are actually the same constant - "_display_name". In addition, it already worked for Box and Google Drive.

Comment: I am checking the file size with the same API but with a different constant for the second parameter passed to the query method - OpenableColumns.SIZE. It's working good for other clouds, except for OneDrive which always returns 0.

Comment: did you checked content of returned in cursor? Is it possible that projection is ignored, so column index isn't 0?

Comment: I have just checked it and you are right! projection is ignored, all columns are returned and not only the requested one and therefore column index is not the right one. Any idea how to get only the requested column? or i have no choice but to iterate over all columns and search for the relevant one?

Comment: Ok, i found cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME) that returns the relevant column index. No need to iterate over all columns. Question is if the projection ignoring is a bug? because the column name is indeed android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME (_display_name)